# creating a method that returns multiple values

Tags: python

I have a function which creates two dataframes. The actual example is bigger but lets says its like this:

```
def createDataFrames()
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Tag 1', 'Tag2'], columns=['Tag'])
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Tag 3', 'Tag4'], columns=['Tag'])

   return(df1)
   return(df2)
```

Now I was under the assumption that I could store the dataframe like this

```
 df1, df2 = createDataFrames()
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/contexta-misc-python-scripts/tag_prediction/test13.py", line 11, in <module>
 df1, df2 = createDataFrames()
 ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return one object, a tuple, instead:

```
return df1, df2
```

(It is the comma that makes `df1, df2` a tuple object with two elements).

`return` *ends* a function right there and then; there is no concept of multiple `return` statements, so the second `return(df2)` is simply never executed.

Also note that `return` is a statement, not a function. You don't need parentheses.

Comment: Also interesting to point out that `df1, df2` is actually just one value...a tuple!